# Print each word from this sentence

Tags: java, cpu-word, sentence

I have the following sentence:

```
This is a text and we should print each word
```

I want to print each word from this sentence.

```
package lab2_3;

public  class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s2 = "This is a text and we should print each word";


        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i <= s2.length() - 1; i++){
            if (s2.substring(i).startsWith(" ") || i == 0){

                //here I search for the start of the sentence or " "
                for (j = i + 1; j <= s2.length() - 1; j++){

                    if (s2.substring(j).startsWith(" ") || j == s2.length() - 1) {
                        //here I search for the next " " or the end of the sentence
                        System.out.println(s2.substring(i, j));
                        //printing
                        i = j;
                        //i=j because the next search must be done from where we left

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This
 is
 a
 text
 and
 we
 should
 print
 each
 wor
```

As you can see it almost works, but the letter d is missing from the last word.
A possible solution is to add " " at the end and it will work, but I don't want to do that.

Can you please tell me where it is my mistake and how to fix it ?

Also, can you please provide a better solution for this.

Comment: I can see if i print like this :   System.out.println(s2.substring(i, j+1)); ,it will work, but stil no clue why it does not work in the first place.

Comment: Side note: `i <= s2.length() - 1` why not simply `i < s2.length()`? It is a lot clearer.

Comment: As for a better solution: `Arrays.stream(s2.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.joining(System.getProperty("line.separator")))`

Comment: @ReutSharabani I still think that `for (String word : s2.split("\\s+")){System.out.println(word);}` is cleaner.

Comment: @Pshemo Well, they do not do the same thing... You never produce the output string which could be good or bad depending on the use case. I really like the stream API and find it very clean for most uses.

Comment: @ReutSharabani "You never produce the output string" fair enough, how about `String.join(System.lineSeparator(), s2.split("\\s+"))`? True stream API can be very nice but IMO it is overused.

Comment: @Pshemo yeah that's better. I keep forgetting java has `join` now. And I've never seen `System.lineSeparator()` (but I usually have a static collector for my solution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. String already have `split(regexDelimiter)` method which accepts regex representing place on which you want to split.

Also [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) allows us to easily iterate over all elements of array or implementations of Iterable interface

```
for (String str : strArray){
   //do something with str
}
```

Since Java 8 we have also `String.join(delimiter, elements)` method which can create string representing `element0[delimiter]element1[delimiter]..`.

So depending what you are looking for you may want to use

```
for (String word : s2.split(" ")){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

or

```
String inEachLine = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), s2.split(" "));
```

or maybe even simpler

```
String inEachLine = s2.replace(" ", System.lineSeparator());
```

Last example simply creates new String based on original one, This new string will have replaced each space with OS dependant line separator (like for Windows `\r\n`).

---

You can also use additional class designed to help us reading data from string. This class is `Scanner`. So in your case you could simply use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s2);
while(sc.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string in array

```
String s2 = "This is a text and we should print each word";

    String [] s3 = s2.split(" ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s3.length; i++)
      System.out.println(s3[i]);

 }
```

If you don't want to hard code for space you can use a regex

```
String s2 = "This is a text and we should print each word";

    String [] s3 = s2.split("\\s");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s3.length; i++)
    System.out.println(s3[i]);

}
```

Output

```
This
is
a
text
and
we
should
print
each
word
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare the `String`
2. Split the string into an array using the `split()` method on the `String` object
3. Loop over each element in the array and print it to the screen

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String slashString = "This is a text and we should print each word";

    for(String word : slashString.split(" ")){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This
is
a
text
and
we
should
print
each
word
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    String s2 = "This is a text and we should print each word";
    String[] t = s2.split("(?= )");
    for (String e : t)
        System.out.println(e);
```

result

```
This
 is
 a
 text
 and
 we
 should
 print
 each
 word
```